# Find | Grep | Sed to find a string inside a functions.php for all my websites in whm

Tags: linux, bash, shell

pls I need a grand favor here, I can't find the code to exec what I need.

Here we go: I need to find a string inside a path of all my websites, like that path:

```
grep -iRl "wpfeed" */public_html/wp-content/themes/*/
```

but have a problem, with the `/themes/*/` <- they find all strings in all files that I don't needed. What I want is:

```
grep -iRl "wpfeed" */public_html/wp-content/themes/*/functions.php.
```

BUT - they don't find nothing.

[like in that image, nothing apperars with my code][1]

and, if they find a string "wpfeed" they need to delete the line 2 at 183 with the command

```
sed '2,4d' file
```

just in case, have above a print about all my directories that I need to scan:

```
root@odin.agenciaalper.com.br [home]# /bin/ls -Rl */public_html/wp-content/themes/*/functions.php | head -10
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcompensadoscom abcompensadoscom  18731 Nov 26  2018 abcompensadoscom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 abpmcom          abpmcom           26240 Jun 27  2018 abpmcom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 agenciaalpercom  agenciaalpercom   30337 Apr 17  2019 agenciaalpercom/public_html/wp-content/themes/thefox3/functions.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 agenciaalpercom  agenciaalpercom   36620 Oct  2  2018 agenciaalpercom/public_html/wp-content/themes/TheFox/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 agencialoncom    agencialoncom     24496 Jun  3 12:46 agencialoncom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 allcarcentercom  allcarcentercom   18731 May 13  2019 allcarcentercom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 amarekombuchacom amarekombuchacom  19670 Apr 29 14:26 amarekombuchacom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 amaropisoscom    amaropisoscom     24016 May 18  2019 amaropisoscom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 amigaopneuscom   amigaopneuscom    26159 Jul 28 12:47 amigaopneuscom/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 amplitudeacustic amplitudeacustic  24436 Jun 27 14:03 amplitudeacustic/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/functions.php
```

Comment: Copy/paste actual dir listing `/bin/ls -Rl */public_html/wp-content/themes/*/functions.php | head -10` into the body of your Q. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Don't expect readers to goto external sites to understand your problem. Posting images is not helpful, as readers cannot use their web-browser's search tool to look for specific text AND if the reader wanted to recreate your problem, they would have to type in a bunch of data, instead of copy/paste from your question (Q). Good luck.

Comment: We really can't debug why you're not matching `wpfeed` in any of the `function.php` files. Simplify your testing by understanding why it's not working in one file first. Make a test file w 3 lines copied from a `function.php` with one line containing `wpfeed` and get that to work. `unix2dos function.php` might help. ..... `grep` will always work, there is some other problem you haven't identified.

Comment: Once you have that working, make a small test dir, with 3-5 files copied from your main directory. Get that to work. now grep -iRl wpfeed testDir/path/to/function.php | xargs sed -S '2,4d' {}` may work. Confirm via `sed --help` that your `sed` supports `-S` option. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem... Is the set of the path haha, my bad!

Can u help me to do the validation? Like:

Comment: IF HAVE THE STRING - delete the line 2 at 183, if doeset, do nothing

Comment: Isn't that why you're using `grep -l` (LIST)? Only filesnames that matched are Listed. This automatically skips *"if doeset, do nothing"*. My `grep ... | xargs sed ...` in above comment should help. BUT test first! (I can't see what you're doing, so be careful!).

Comment: Here is the git of the file that I want to verify if the string start_wp_theme_tmp exists, and then if have need to delete the line 2 at 183
https://github.com/Danton4879/functions.php/blob/master/filetoverify

Comment: #!/bin/bash
VIRUS=$(grep -w "$end_wp_theme_tmp" functions.php)
if test -n "$VIRUS" ; then
    sed '2,183d' functions.php
else
    echo "have nothing"
fi

Comment: but that doesen't work for me

Comment: so do you get the "nave nothing" message? If that is true, then something is wrong with your `grep -w "$end_wp_theme_tmp" functions.php`. This is very different than you posted before. Also, virus's in WP is an often posted problem here. Did you look at the existing Q/A on this issue? AND `grep -w` is not the same as `grep -iRl` as you posted in your original Q. Again, I can't see what your doing. I can only advise small tests to figure out what is not working. You're paniced, but rushing thru isn't helping. Sorry and Good luck!

Comment: ALSO, `grep` won't be able to find a multi-line virus code embedded. It can only look at one line of a file at a time. If the virus contains any `\n` newline chars, you won't be able to match it with grep.

Comment: If you decide to take my advice from my very first comment, then please let me know, otherwise without the proper evidence, I won't be able to help you. AGAIN, don't post links/images to external sources to define your problem. Edit your Q to show the relevant portions.

Comment: I did what you say! Sorry buddy!

Comment: is in the head post

Comment: Ok I will explain better. The line that starts in 2 and go at 183, is where the malicious code creates a lot pf directories and malicious files too. So I have a virus removator in php that when he find the wp-temp comment in the functions.php they remove all the lines that I have mention for u

Comment: But I need to do that in all my websites, and do one by one its hard, and also if I can do that in a cron on the server, will have a verification automating the process

Comment: So, what I want is that: If find the string $end_wp_theme_tmp in all functions.php on the server, they need to delete the line 2 3 4 5 ... 183 and is it

Comment: And about the having nothing message, I don't know what can I say bcause I don't understand the Q

Comment: your code :`#!/bin/bash VIRUS=$(grep -w "$end_wp_theme_tmp" functions.php) if test -n "$VIRUS" ; then sed '2,183d' functions.php else echo "have nothing" fi`. Does it produce the message "have nothing"? Please reread my comments about this above re `-w` and other issues. Also ...

Comment: you have the right idea with `'2,183d', but you need `sed -i `2,183d' functions.php`. The `-i` is important BUT it will permantly change your files. If you don't have a backup then you'll have trouble fixing any lines that got deleted that shouldn't have been deleted. To be safe, the better way to do it would be `cp /path/to/functions.php /path/to/functions.php.sav; sed -i '' '2,183d' /path/to/functions.php`. Then you have backups. Restoring them will be a hassle, but not as bad as incorrectly deleted php code. .....

Comment: If I were you, I would shut down my websites, as you can't be sure what other damage is being done if they are still running. But I'm not an expert on this.

Comment: Assuming that you have no backups, you need to get a script that does the right thing and doesn't create new problems AND you need to get it to work right on one website before you try to fix **all** of your websites. Some thing like `find /www -name 'functions.php' | grep -l 'VirusStart' | xargs sed -S -i '' '2,183d' {}` inside a shell script might be all you need, but you have to TEST IT. Note that `/www` is just a place holder, use the correct based directory for where code is saved. ....

Comment: If you have trouble in your test environment, then post a new Q based on this idea with you best attempt to solve the problem AND include small sets of sample files and directory structures. Also mention that you are trying to clean up a virus infection in your WP sites. Sorry, but I'm going to bed, so your best bet is to bost a new Q based on the above. Good luck.

Comment: AND as you say *'code creates a lot pf directories and malicious files'* consider adding another step in the `find /www ...` script that deletes all of those files and dirs. Good luck, going to bed.